# Android Room - Migration of new table fails with error "Table already exists"

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Crashlytics notify about an error with migration on the production version of my app.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table NotificationsRoomEntity already exists (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE NotificationsRoomEntity (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                sentDate TEXT NOT NULL,
                title TEXT NOT NULL,
                message TEXT NOT NULL,
                type TEXT NOT NULL,
                commandId INTEGER NOT NULL,
                readDate TEXT,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            )
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
```

This table is new in my app and cannot exist in the past. What circumstances are the reason for these exceptions? The migration tests are running successfully, and there was no table with this name in the previous schemas. In some sources I have seen the "**CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS**" procedure, but can I be sure that the table will be up-to-date if it really already exists? My migration code is below.

```
    val MIGRATION_6_7 = object : Migration(6, 7) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL(
            """
                CREATE TABLE NotificationsRoomEntity (
                    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    sentDate TEXT NOT NULL,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    message TEXT NOT NULL,
                    type TEXT NOT NULL,
                    commandId INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    readDate TEXT,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                )
            """
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: do you happen to have an AutoMigration for (6,7)? I'm thinking it might have generated your new table before getting the chance to run the manual migration script and hence the table already existing. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/AutoMigration Even if you don't have it, you could take a look at it, it might be more optimal for just adding a new Entity

Comment: @MonicaIvan, thanks for the answer. I also thought of automatic migration, but the room version in my project is 2.3.0. AutoMigrtation appeared in 2.40.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" procedure, but can I be sure that the table will be up-to-date if it really already exists? My migration code is below.

You can use:-

```
val MIGRATION_6_7 = object : Migration(6, 7) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NotificationsRoomEntity;")
    database.execSQL(
        "
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NotificationsRoomEntity (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                sentDate TEXT NOT NULL,
                title TEXT NOT NULL,
                message TEXT NOT NULL,
                type TEXT NOT NULL,
                commandId INTEGER NOT NULL,
                readDate TEXT,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
        "
    )
    }
}
```

Then you will know that the table will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It's a good idea, I'll try it. But the question of "why this is happening?" still remains. Because I have already faced this error before. The previous time was with "Column already exists"

Comment: @AzamatAzhimkulov, there simply isn't enough to go on. It would appear that somehow, the migration would appear to being done but then somehow the version number (user_version in the database header) is reverting to 6 and hence the migration runs again. You don't by any chance backup/restore the database according to it's file name, in which case it could be because of the -wal file containing changes after the changes to the schema have been checkpointed but not the version number (not even sure if that would be possible though).

Comment: I have a theory the migration failure is due to fallbackToDestructiveMigration. There are no transitions from version 3 to version 5 in the list of my migrations. But then why do crashes occur for all users, even those who migrate from version 6 to version 7, or am I missing something?

Comment: fallbackToDestructiveMigration only falls back if there is no Migration coded. As per 
@AzamatAzhimkulov *"Allows Room to destructively recreate database tables if Migrations that would migrate old database schemas to the latest schema version are not found."* https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbackToDestructiveMigration(). So don't code a Migration (noting that you will lose all data).